# Python and Node : Image Upload

Tags: node.js, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to Python and Node, I'm attempting to do a simple image upload. Python for the client side and Node for the server side. The image is uploaded and looks to be the correct size, but when I try to open or preview the image I get a prompt saying the following :

"The file could not be opened . It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognise"

**NOTE* I was able to get the upload to work using multer, see my posted answer. However , I would still I like to figure out why image open or image preview fails.**

Client code (test locally) :

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:3000/upload"
image = open('test1.jpg','rb').read()
file = {'file': image}
r = requests.post(url, files=file)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

---

Server code snippet :

```
const Fs = require('fs')

...
...
router.post('/upload', (req, res) =>{
        var data = '';
        req.setEncoding('binary');
        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function(){
            Fs.writeFile("tester.jpg", data, 'binary', function(err) {
                if(err) throw err

                res.send("Image uploaded ...");

            });
        })
})
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort it out using multer : [npm multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

---

```
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, "./images");
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: Storage
}).single('file');

router.post('/upload', (req, res) =>{
    console.log("upload ...");

    upload(req, res, (err) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.send("Failed")
        }
        else{
            console.log(req.file);
            res.send("Uploaded ...");
        }
    });
})
```